# Why can't g++ link a dynamic library created by gcc on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, gcc, sqlite, g++, ubuntu-14.04

I created a C++ wrapper class for the sqlite3 C library and now I want to dinamically link it in my project.
This is the Makefile I'm using

```
CC=gcc
PP=g++
LIBDIR=lib
CCFLAGS=-shared -fPIC -lpthread -ldl
PPFLAGS=-std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -L$(LIBDIR) -Wl,-rpath,./$(LIBDIR) -lsqlite3

INCDIR=src/include
HSRC=src/include/*
CPPSRC=src/*.cpp src/*/*.cpp

SQLITELIB=$(LIBDIR)/libsqlite3.so
SQLITESRC=src/db/sqlite3.c
SQLITEHSRC=src/include/db/sqlite3.h

OUT=server

$(OUT): $(CPPSRC) $(HSRC) $(SQLITELIB)
    $(PP) $(PPFLAGS) $(CPPSRC) -iquote $(INCDIR) -o $(OUT)

$(SQLITELIB): $(SQLITESRC) $(SQLITEHSRC) $(LIBDIR)
    $(CC) $(CCFLAGS) $(SQLITESRC) -o $(SQLITELIB)

$(LIBDIR):
    mkdir $(LIBDIR)
```

And this is the output I get

```
mkdir lib
gcc -shared -fPIC -lpthread -ldl src/db/sqlite3.c -o lib/libsqlite3.so
g++ -std=c++0x -Wall -O3 -Llib -Wl,-rpath,./lib -lsqlite3 src/*.cpp src/*/*.cpp -iquote src/include -o server
/tmp/cchbxzB9.o: nella funzione "db::SQLiteDB::~SQLiteDB()":
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x172): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_close"
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x19a): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_errstr"
/tmp/cchbxzB9.o: nella funzione "db::SQLiteDB::close()":
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x1e2): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_close"
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x20c): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_errstr"
/tmp/cchbxzB9.o: nella funzione "db::SQLiteDB::prepare(std::string, sqlite3_stmt**)":
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x268): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_prepare_v2"
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x28b): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_errstr"
/tmp/cchbxzB9.o: nella funzione "db::SQLiteDB::bindBlob(sqlite3_stmt*, int, void*, int)":
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x2e5): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_bind_blob"
SQLiteDB.cpp:(.text+0x308): riferimento non definito a "sqlite3_errstr"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [server] Errore 1
```

I'm running gcc version 4.8.4 on Ubuntu 14.04, and I think the problem is not in my source code because my collegue is correctly compiling and linking it using gcc version 4.8.5 on Gentoo.
Am I missing something?

Comment: are you using `extern "C"` appropriately? is your colleague using the same makefile?

Comment: Yes, he is. I'm using `sqlite3.h` and `sqlite3.c` which already take care of using `extern "C" `